# ${variable} in javascript not substituted in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, openlayers

I am trying to add direction to a line overlay i have added to map using openlayers. I have created map and line overlay inside my jsp but the problem is that when ${variable} is used in html file, I am getting output as expected with correct direction shown. But when implemented inside jsp all arrows seem to b pointing to just one direction.

I think the problem is that ${variable} in javascript not substituted in jsp.

Here is the piece of code.

direction.jsp

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Line Direction Arrow in OpenLayers</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css"> 
    #map {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
</style> 
<script src="js-libraries/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js-libraries/directions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = null;
    var myNetwork =null;

    function init(){            

        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var ol_osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Simple OSM Map");
        map.addLayers([ol_osm]);

        //vector layer
        var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Line");
        map.addLayer(layer);

        // add edit panel
        var editPanel = new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(layer);
        map.addControl(editPanel);

        //add direction layer 
        OpenLayers.Renderer.symbol.arrow = [0,2, 1,0, 2,2, 1,0, 0,2];
        var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap(OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(
                {graphicName:"arrow",rotation : "${angle}"},
                OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]));
        var dirLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("direction", {styleMap: styleMap});
        map.addLayer(dirLayer);

        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-702335,7043201),15);
        //console.log("Starting map");          
    }

    function updateDirection() {
        //alert(map.layers[2].name);
        map.layers[2].removeAllFeatures();
        var points=[];
        var features =map.layers[1].features;
        //alert(features.length);
        for (var i=0;i<features.length ;i++ )   {
            var linePoints = createDirection(features[i].geometry,get_position_value(),get_foreachseg_value()) ;
            //alert(get_foreachseg_value());
        //  for (var j=0;j<linePoints.length ;j++ ) {
        //      linePoints[j].attributes.lineFid = features[i].fid;
        //  }
            points =points.concat(linePoints);
 //             alert(points);
        }
        map.layers[2].addFeatures(points);
    }

    function get_position_value()   {
        for (var i=0; i < document.direction.position.length; i++)
           {
           if (document.direction.position[i].checked)
              {
              return document.direction.position[i].value;
              }
           }
    }
    function get_foreachseg_value() {           
        if (document.direction.foreachseg.checked){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
 </head>


<body onload="init()">
    <table><tr>
<td><div id="map" class="smallmap"></div></td>
<td><div align="left">
<form name="direction">

    <input type="radio" name="position" value="start"/> start <br>
    <input type="radio" name="position" value="end"/> end  <br>
    <input type="radio" name="position" value="middle" CHECKED/>middle <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foreachseg" /> Create for each segment of line <br>
    <input type=button value="Update" onClick=updateDirection(); />
</form>
</div></td>
</tr></table>     
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway to get the corresponding angle in jsp? the page seems to b working fine when the file was renamed direction.html But when renamed as direction.jsp the angle value is not received correctly. I need to use this with my jsp application. please help.

Thanks and Regards
Ginger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JSP is server side and javascript is client side so you can't pass parameters like this, an alternate would be to add angle as hidden field in your jsp

```
<input type="hidden" value="angle_value_comes_here" id="angle"/>
```

and then access it in javascript using

```
var angle = $('#angle').val();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thankyou @Raunak Kathuria i tried it out and now i can get all angle values in jsp side but when i use it in styleMap it is always taking only the last angle value.

Comment: That solution is good for single value, for multiple values you can store json as hidden value <input id="jsonV" type="hidden" value='{"products":{"id":1,"name":"sample"}}'> and fetch it with var jsonObj = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('jsonV').value) but this is not the optimal solution. Better would be to request server if its fine with you through ajax call requesting json. You can use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ in init function

Comment: Thankyou  Raunak Kathuria. I have followed the first method you hav mentioned where i will be getting all angle values and then parse it to get correct angle values. Now its working perfectly. Thanks a lot. I am posting my updated code below...

Comment: Glad it helped :) please upvote the comment if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my updated code in here.

```
    function updateDirection() {
                    flagMarkerStatus = 5;
                    var angles = 0;
        dirLayer.removeAllFeatures();
                    var linePoints=[];
        var points=[];
        var features =lineLayer.features;
                    document.getElementById("angle").value="";
        for (var i=0;i<features.length ;i++ )   {
            var linePoints = createDirection(features[i].geometry,"middle",true);
            points =points.concat(linePoints);
                    angles = document.getElementById("angle").value; 
                    //'angle' div contains angle values seperated by '~'
                    angles=angles.replace(/\[|\]/g, '');
                    angles=angles.split("~");                                

                for(var i=0;i<linePoints.length;i++){

                    var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap(OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(
                            {graphicName:"arrow",rotation : angles[i],strokeWidth: 3,strokeColor: "#ff0000"},
                            OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]));    
                     dirLayer.styleMap = styleMap;                       
                    dirLayer.addFeatures(linePoints[i]);                    

                } 

        }  



    }
```